# first/last row of table in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I have a question regarding smarty templates, I'm using PHP and Smarty in order to generate pages. I would like to somehow count or determine first and last row of table. So I can set different CSS for first and last TR or leave it as it is, if it's only 1 TR.

Hope it makes sense what im after. Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table-paddings-2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th class="table-gray-th-noborder">Search Type</th>
        <th class="table-gray-th-noborder">Average Turnaround Time</th>
    </tr>
{foreach key=obk item=row from=$report}
    <tr>
        <td class="td-border-top-only text-align-left">{$row.SearchName}</td>
        <td class="td-border-top-only text-align-left">{$row.tt}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is your friend: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Examples 7.12, 7.13:

```
{* show LATEST on the first item, otherwise the id *}
<table>
{foreach from=$items key=myId item=i name=foo}
<tr>
  <td>{if $smarty.foreach.foo.first}LATEST{else}{$myId}{/if}</td>
  <td>{$i.label}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: To be honest, I completely forgot to check documentation. MANY thanks for saving me time!